# I can't click button in Bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

I have a problem with bootstrap popover.I have a button, when i click in this, it show a form. In a form have a button,I want when I click this, it alert something. But when I click it, it not alert something. I don't know why it not working, can you help me? Thanks you everybody!

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_popover #ok').click(function(){
      alert("hi");
    });
    $('.btn-open-popover').popover();

    // //popover option
    $("#a-popover").popover({
      title: 'Dang ki thong tin',
      content: $('#divContentHTML').html(),
      placement: 'right',
      html: true
    }); 
  });
 </script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
 <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="a-popover">Click!</a>
        <div id="divContentHTML" style="display:none">
         <form method="post" id="form_popover">
           <div class="form-group form-inline kc">
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Input field">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Input field">
           </div>
           <button type="button" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
          </form>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this button is loaded (or reinitialized) dynamically, you should use delegated event handler. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ok', function()
{
    alert("hi");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6ohszx0/).

Or a little better with static `<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">`:

```
$('.col-xs-5').on('click', '#ok', function()
{
    alert("hi");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6ohszx0/2/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use event delegate for dynamic generated elemnts

```
  $(document).on('click', '#ok',function(){
            alert("hi");
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3gcgxym/)